# How to limit the vertical space that the user can drag an element in, using react-native-gesture-handler?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

I'm trying to build a sliding menu from the bottom of the screen. The main problem I'm facing is setting a limit to how far up the user can drag the menu.

**Background:**

I've looked through examples on the [react-native-gesture-handler github](https://github.com/kmagiera/react-native-gesture-handler/tree/master/Example). Tried to fiddle around with the [bouncing example](https://github.com/kmagiera/react-native-gesture-handler/blob/master/Example/bouncing/index.js). But still couldn't figure out exactly what I need to do to set a limit.

**Code:**

Currently my setup is as follows:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    Animated,
   Text,
   View,
   Image } from 'react-native';
import { 
   PanGestureHandler, 
   USE_NATIVE_DRIVER, 
   State } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

export default class Menu extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);

        this._translateY = new Animated.Value(0);
      this._lastOffset = { y: 0 };
      this._onPanGestureEvent = Animated.event(
         [
            {
               nativeEvent: {
                  translationY: this._translateY,
               }
            }
         ], 
            {
               useNativeDriver: USE_NATIVE_DRIVER
            }
      );
      this._onHandlerStateChange = event => {
            if (event.nativeEvent.oldState === State.ACTIVE) {
               this._lastOffset.y += event.nativeEvent.translationY;
               this._translateY.setOffset(this._lastOffset.y);
               this._translateY.setValue(0);
            }
      };
   }

   render() {
      return (
         <View 
            style={{
               position: 'absolute', 
               left: 0, 
               right: 0, 
               top: 0, 
               bottom: 0,
               flex: 3,
               flexDirection: 'column',
               justifyContent: 'flex-end',
               alignItems: 'stretch'
            }}>
            <Animated.View style={
                     [
                        {
                           height: 60,
                        }, 
                        {
                           transform: [
                              {
                                 translateY: this._translateY
                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     ]
               }>
               <PanGestureHandler
               {...this.props}
               onGestureEvent={this._onPanGestureEvent}
               onHandlerStateChange={this._onHandlerStateChange}>
                  <View 
                     style={
                        {
                           height: 60,
                           backgroundColor: 'white',
                           borderWidth: 0.5,
                           borderColor: '#ccc',
                        }
                     }>
                     <Text style={{height: '100%', paddingLeft: 20, paddingTop: 20}}>Hello world</Text>
                  </View>
               </PanGestureHandler>

               <View style={
                        {
                           height: 200,
                           backgroundColor: 'white',
                           borderWidth: 0.5,
                           borderColor: '#ccc',
                        }
                     }>
                  <Text style={{height: '100%', paddingLeft: 20, paddingTop: 20}}>
                    Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello 
                    world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello 
                    world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello 
                    world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello 
                    world Hello world Hello world Hello world 
                  </Text>
               </View>
            </Animated.View>
         </View>
      )
   }
}
```

which gives this result:

[Collapsed menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGSrq.png)

when i swipe up i get:

[Expanded menu, but out of bounds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQd00.png)

and when i swipe all the way down, the menu goes out of view:

[Shrunk menu, but out of bounds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spS0I.png)

**Goal:**

I'd like the menu to pop up to It's full size once swiped up and then shrink back down to just the title when swiped down.

Swiping up should end up like this: 
[Expected result when swiping up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMJYR.png)

Swiping down should end up like this:
[Expected result when swiping down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGSrq.png)

Thank you in advance for any help you might provide, it'll be really appreciated.